# How to use observable subject variable in component?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a shared service with providers in my root component. I an using this service to manipulate parent for the count of items selected. On the parent this count is surrounded by anchor so it takes user to all items selected. However i am using a variable of shared service to do this, while i believe there should be some way so that i can call observable to fetch the info. My code for service is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Promo } from './model';

@Injectable()
export class CheckoutEventService {
    private checkOutSucess = new Subject<boolean>();
    //private checkOutFailureMsg = new Subject<string>();
    private checkedOutPromo = new Subject<Promo>();
    //I could not find to remove this and use above property somehow.
    public bogusPromoObject :Promo;

    checkOutPromo$ = this.checkedOutPromo.asObservable();
    checkOutSucess$ = this.checkOutSucess.asObservable();

    checkOutPromoSvc(promo: Promo) {
        this.checkedOutPromo.next(promo);
        this.bogusPromoObject=promo;
    }
    checkOutPromoSucessSvc(msg: boolean) {
        this.checkOutSucess.next(msg);
    }
    }
```

I am now using "bogusPromoObj" to render this behaviour. However i am keen to know if there is a way to reuse the observable to get the history. Just so its clear i am already subscribing to promo observable in parent, however there is a routing involved in next step where i want to fetch history of every item selected.

Comment: Where is bogusPromoObj used?

Comment: I use that in new routed component which displays all the items selected @estus

Comment: It's unclear whether it's used in view or not. The answer depends on that. If it's not then `async` pipe is not applicable.

Comment: Its used in view @estus , I will check below scenario mentioned by you and will confirm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A couple of `checkOutPromo$` observable and `checkOutPromoValue` value is the usual recipe in a situation like this.

If a subject is allowed to have initial value that will be changed later, `BehaviorSubject` can be used:

```
private checkedOutPromo = new BehaviorSubject<Promo|null>(null);
```

Its subscribers will receive current value synchronously. If it's initial, then `null` will be received. Since this subject has current value, it can be retrieved with `checkedOutPromo.value`, this makes `checkOutPromoValue` unnecessary. The value won't be available through `asObservable`, so the subject should become public instead of `checkOutPromo$`. This imposes encapsulation problem; for instance, `checkOutPromo.unsubscribe()` is available for all subscribers but can be harmful.

If `bogusPromoObject` is used only in view, it can be omitted in favour of  `async` pipe:

```
{{ checkoutEventService.checkOutPromo$ | async }}
```